# Can I make an attribute suppress warnings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have made an attribute that automatically assigns value to a variable at runtime as such:

```
    [Assign(AssignmentTime.Awake)]
    private Rigidbody _rigidBody;
```

However, compiler gives out a warning, understandably, that this value is never assigned and will always be null.
Is there a way to make the attribute disable the warning automatically? I don't really want to write that warning suppression #pragma every time I want to use that attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a default value, like `null`. That will make the warning disappear. Your assignment and also inspector assignments will overwrite the default value later on.

```
[Assign(AssignmentTime.Awake)]
private Rigidbody _rigidBody = null;
```

Comment: I can't believe this is actually working. It still underlines it in IDE but Unity no longer shows it as a warning. Not ideal, but will do. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the warning is either in the ide or the unity console. i prefer the unity console to be as free as possible.

Comment: Explicitly assigning null now causes a different warning: CS0649: Field 'field' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 'value'

Answer (score 3):

To be explicit: no, you cannot suppress a warning via a custom attribute. You *can* use:

- `[SuppressMessage(...)]` in addition to your attribute
- `#pragma warning {disable|enable} {codes}`

Both of which are available via the warning's popup in the IDE